# と使います: Why と is used instead of を？

Tags: particles, particle-と

I am preparing for my exam and have a question about the purpose of using と in a sentence.  Does anyone know why と is used but not を before the verb 使います in the sentence below?

From my textbook みんなの日本語 II (pg.67):

> 「頑張る」は日本人がよく使う言葉です。スポーツの試合で「頑張れ」、スビーチのまえに「頑張ってね」、いっしょに何かをするとき、「頑張ろう」など**と**使います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think と is being used here instead of を　because it is indicating a quotation or the words that are being said. And also 使う here possesses the meaning of speak + use.

You **USE** this word.

Not in the sense of using an item. So it is a bit like 言う　here.

You might also be interested in と感じられる、と思う、と見える。